# Error Logs from Hybrid Mobile App that loads a PHP file

Tags: php, hybrid-mobile-app

I just wanna ask if any Mobile especially Hybrid App developer here know how to see error logs from a loaded php file.

I have a hybrid app that will post data to a php file from my website and that php file will load in the screen of my hybrid app, everything is fine, data were received by php and mysql but I wasn't able to see the image file in the location where I designated it. I have no idea what kind of error it could be so I realised that I'm not using anything to see any error logs from a php file that loaded in my hybrid app, all I can do is to see error logs from the hybrid app itself by using Safari Develop Features(for iOS). Can anyone suggest a solution for this? Thank you!

Comment: Which os runs the php server? Then search for "php error logs on [your_os]" and you'll find the solution to your question.

Comment: I was able to do this but It will just show me how to locate php log file. Thanks though. I was just trying to figure out how developers check php error logs on a running hybrid mobile app

Comment: Yes: you have to locate the error logs. Then open the file and you can see which error caused the script to stop. If this is not the answer you were looking for, then your question is not clear. Reading it I understand you don't know where to read the errors. Doesn't this?